# Control panel switches to HTTPS protocol on its own

Tags: control-panel, admin, https, ssl

On one Craft CMS site I have, all control panel URLs I call over HTTP are rewritten to HTTPS. E.g. the login page, as well as all its assets, are being served via `https://www.mywebsite.com/admin/…`.

The rest of the site is available via `https://www.mywebsite.com/`

I've already tried to enforce HTTP via mod.rewrite in .htaccess, as well as explicitly setting `baseCpUrl` and an new `cpTrigger` in `config/general` – with no success at all.

Is this a feature that I can deactivate? A bug in Craft CMS 2.4.2670?
Or is this a server-side issue?

Comment: This is going to be something on the server side.  Maybe share your `.htaccess` file as well as what's in your `craft/config/general.php` file?

Comment: At first, I blamed the server, too, since my other Craft instances on other servers work flawlessly. But: why only the control panel, not the main site? How can one trigger a different protocol than the other? Anyway, here are my current .htaccess and config/general.php files: http://avantlalettre.ch/files/htaccess.txt ; http://avantlalettre.ch/files/config-general.txt — Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: Try removing everything after `RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]` in your `.htaccess` file and see if that helps.

Comment: So the server is switching to https and you want http instead?   That won't happen automatically since you'd need a certificate, server config, etc.  Sounds like there's more directives in apache's config/virtual host config.. Who runs your server? That's where I'd start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out **not to be Craft's fault**, indeed:

On the server, the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` environment variable was erroneously set to `https` in the reverse proxy – an issue that my hosting provider had to resolve.

(As a quick fix, the following line in `index.php` did the trick, too:)

```
 apache_setenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'http');
```

Thanks to @brad-bell and @ritterknight for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted. Those sorts of problems can be maddening...